# Lazy image loading with GWT

Tags: javascript, image, gwt, lazy-loading

Jquery and other JS frameworks got many lazy image loading plugins, code-blocks. Which basically loads image when its visible in visible area of browser.

How to achieve it in GWT? I am aware that I can use jquery plugin in GWT, but Looking for native GWT solution.

So, I would like to do something like this..

```
LazyImage img = new LazyImage("load.gif","original_thumb.png")
scrollContainer.add(img); //scrollContainer is added to ScrollPanel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the solution from Jason. Except that the image itself decides when it needs to get loaded.

```
class LazyImage extends Image {

    private String fUrl;
    private ScrollPanel fParent;
    private boolean fLoaded;

    public LazyImage(String url, ScrollPanel parent) {
        fUrl = url;
        fParent = parent;
        attachHandlers();
    }

    private void attachHandlers() {
        fParent.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                int imageTop = getAbsoluteTop();
                int viewport = fParent.getAbsoluteTop() + fParent.getOffsetHeight();
                if (imageTop < viewport) {
                    lazyLoad();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        fLoaded = false;
        fUrl = url;
    }

    public void lazyLoad() {
        if (!fLoaded) {
            super.setUrl(fUrl);
            fLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: theoretically this should work. Havent tried practically.. solution was needed quickly so used jquery lazyload plugin(http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).. but will try this too...thnx for answer.

Comment: I think you should remove the ScrollHandler after the image has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This should be somewhat straightforward. There are two basic steps.

1.) Create a widget that can be told to load an image programatically instead of automatically showing it.  Store the URL of the image to load and have a method to load it.

```
public class LazyImage extends Image {
  private String url;

  // Override behavior of base Image constructor to just store the URL.
  public LazyImage(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public void lazyLoad() {
    super.setUrl(url);
  }
}
```

This can be used in much the same way as the regular `Image` class, except you will need to call `lazyLoad()` to actually get the image to appear.

2.) Detect when the image is needed using a `ScrollPanel`.

I'm not totally sure of the code for this off the top of my head, but it will basically boil down to comparing the image's location vs. the scroll panel's scroll position. If the scroll position >= the image's distance from the top of the scroll panel, call `lazyLoad()` and the image will appear.

I haven't tried any of this code out, it's just a sketch of something that should work. Feel free to ask questions or give feedback if it works/doesn't work for you.

Comment: thanks Jason. I appreciate your help. when I asked questioned I already figured what you have done. I mean that was the easy part :)